# Create folder and save file into that folder and then extract zip file

Tags: python, django, zip

I have this code which creates a folder base on the logged in user and saves the file they are uploading into that folder. The file the user is uploading is a zip file which I want to have extracted upon upload.

The problem is that this code doesn't work because it exits the folder after creation, so it comes up with an IO error saying it couldnt find the file.

How would I go on fixing this problem?

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    zip = ZipFile(filename)
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user, filename) and zip.extract()
```

> Exception Value:
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'UploadedFile.zip'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several suggestions:

- you have to create the 'user_{0}' directory first
- `os.join()` is canonical for making a path
- your function returns a boolean value, not sure it is what you intended

Comment: Thank you. I've made some based on your answer. createfolder = os.path.join('C:/', 'Users', 'myuser', 'Desktop', 'Project', 'Fileuploads', time_stamp,)
 mkdir(createfolder) - but it returns those double slashes "\\" in the path which gives me an IO error. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The double clashes are perfectly ok, that is standard representation of a path. On Windows there are some issues with letter drive maybe that is causing problem https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: For simplicity you can try: folder = `os.path.join('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\Project\\Fileuploads', str(time_stamp))`

Comment: Yup just noticed. This doesnt happen on my Ubuntu instance.

Comment: Im still getting file not found even though it mentions the full correct path

Comment: Never mind im just stupid. The way Windows constructs paths is not the same on Linux. All good - Thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: If you are on python 3.6, `pathlib.Path` should be more convenient. Good luck with the paths!